# Can't install drivers for HP Laserjet Pro M12a on Windows 10 machines

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer

This actual problem of mine, with this HP Printer, announced to be compatible with Windows 10, has been quite annoying already for some 6wks, and I haven't so far got any real corrective solution for it from HP Support.

When trying to install, or re-trying after cleaning the previous trial and re-starting the machine, the full driver -> hp_LJPM11-M13_Full_Solution-v20160225-10229428-signed.exe (95.4 MB) from Nov, 5th 2016 for 64-bit, I always get with the Windows 10 machines for USB to the same result -> The printer is got seen on the Devices and Printers, but with an exclamation mark and note "Driver Disorder", and it do NOT! work/print …  And, further, the Printer troubleshooting will give the error message -> Object HP EWS is missing!

This problem arises on my client's two all up-to-date  Windows 10 Home 1803 17134.345 machines for USB, but on his Windows 7 Pro SP1 machine the USB-installation is working all well!

So, why on earth it is missing on Windows 10, but on Windows 7 it's probably existing ... And, where to find/get it and then got it installed, maybe before the printer driver install, when/if needed?

Asked additions 21.11.2018:
1) Yes, the installation .exe did extract all the files successfully with admin rights and all the installation procedure went through smoothly, but the final result was as described, install did not fully success and the  troubleshooting was reporting about the missing object
2) The *.inf wasn't checked/touched

Comment: Please click on [edit] and then give us a step-by-step, line-by-line, recap if what you have done. Folks helping use Comments; instead, you reply by enhancing the original question with [edit].  1) Did you extract the driver files first, into a directory where you have rights, and then run the executable? 2) Did you look through the files for an *.INF file, and try to right click and select Install?